# No hace nada el botón

Tags: java, android, studio

No entiendo porque el botón no funciona, hace unas horas me funcionaba y no he estado tocando nada, al fin y al cabo lo que hace el botón es llamar a un método y este método ya lo he comprobado 200 veces y no hay nada mal.

El botón no funciona pero tampoco da ningún error, lo máximo que he visto que salga al darle es esto:

> removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time

Y no sé qué quiere decir.

```
public class EscanerFragment extends Fragment {

EditText etCodigo;
Button btnEscanearCodigo;


public EscanerFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_escaner, container, false);

    etCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.etCodigo);
    btnEscanearCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_escanear);

    btnEscanearCodigo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            escanear();
        }
    });

    return vista;
}

public void escanear(){
    IntentIntegrator intent = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(EscanerFragment.this);
    intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    intent.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
    intent.setCameraId(0);
    intent.setBeepEnabled(true);
    intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
    intent.initiateScan();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents() == null){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Has salido del escaneo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            etCodigo.setText(result.getContents().toString());
        }
    }else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Aquí dejo la captura del recyclerview, como puedes ver solo me sale 1 y me toca hacer scroll para poder ver los otros, pero yo quiero que se vean los 3 o 4 últimos sin tener que hacer scroll.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la clase EscanerActivity donde tengo varios métodos para poder borrar un código y para volver atrás con botones, además inicializo el recyclerview y fuerzo a que lleve varios archivos. Creo que me falta algún listener en la clase donde tengo el método **escanear()**; pero ni idea la verdad.

```
public class EscanerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ModificarFragment.OnEscanerEliminadoListener, ModificarFragment.AtrasListadoEscanerListener, RecyclerViewFragment.OnEscaner_Listener {

public ArrayList<Escaner> escaneres;

public EscanerActivity() {
    this.escaneres = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_escaner);

    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    RecyclerViewFragment fragment = RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance();

     escaneres.add(new Escaner("AAAAAAA"));
     escaneres.add(new Escaner("EEEEEEE"));
     escaneres.add(new Escaner("VVVVVVV"));

     fragment.escaneres = this.escaneres;
     transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment).addToBackStack(null);

     transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void OnProductoEliminado(Escaner e) {
    escaneres.remove(e);

    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    RecyclerViewFragment fragment = RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance();
    fragment.escaneres = this.escaneres;
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

@Override
    public void AtrasListadoEscaneresClick() {
        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    RecyclerViewFragment fragment = RecyclerViewFragment.newInstance();
    fragment.escaneres = this.escaneres;

    transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment);

    transaction.commit();
}


    @Override
    public void onEscaneresClick(Escaner escaner){
        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ModificarFragment fragment = ModificarFragment.newInstance();
        fragment.escaneres = escaner;

        transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment);

        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: podrias intentar poner el onclick dentro del método escanear, no dentro del oncreate.

Comment: Tampoco funciona, creo que voy a rehacerlo en otro proyecto, tengo que haber tocado algo sin darme cuenta, quizás así vea el error. Otra pregunta, sabes porque el recyclerview no se me muestra entero y me toca hacer scroll? Quiero que se vean los últimos 3 o 4 elementos, pero sin hacer scroll, arriba dejo captura.

Comment: @MatiasNavarro creo que el fallo no esta en el botón, ya que si hago el escaner solo si que me funciona, es al añadirle los fragments siguientes con sus funcionalidades cuando se me rompe el botón